# css background images blink after reload page

Tags: html, css, image, caching, background

I have blocks on page with background images, when I refer (click link) to the same page-images blink. How can I set chache or something else to extract this problem?

### I tell about web http://pohladovybeton.sk/, especially in IE 8 after redirect (in page menus) is browser blink, and in Opera is blink content background, in FF is all OK and I want that it will be same in other browsers

if I click "Kontakt" (top-right in menu) it is ok (there is downloading google map), How can I to score it in other pages (some delay or what)?

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox, in IE it does blink a bit and I don't really understand why. Is there any transparency in the image?

Comment: content background image is transparency png created in gimp, but although I disable his transparency - situation is same

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can stop this entirely, it is normal browser behaviour. Even with a cache, if you reload then browsers will often fetch images again, hence the 'blinking'.

Answer (score 0):

What does the link do? If it reloads content, then how would you expect to not reload the images (as they are content).

If you want to update a specific piece of information on the page, you can use some form of AJAX to only load that piece. If you just want to go to the top of the page, use

```
<a href="#">return to top</a>
```